# NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils Tomcat 6

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc, tomcat6

So essentially I am using maven to organize my project in the same way I have always done, but I am getting an error in catalina.out telling me that it cannot find the StringUtils class in com.mysql.jdbc even though I can see that the jar is in the war classpath. I have not had the same problem with Tomcat7 on a different server leading me to believe that there is a library class somewhere obscuring the jar file I have in the actual project. Here is the exception:

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils

My maven dependency is as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.20</version>
        </dependency>
```

I just cannot fathom how the class is not found in the classpath when I can see the jar in the lib part of WEB-INF and I can see the class in the jar. Does anybody have an idea on what could be happening here? Thanks for any help.

If you need more information just let me know.

Full Stacktrace: (I use Apache's BasicDataSource).

```
    Throwable occurred: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'voiceManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.voiceforge.api.swift.VoiceManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/vf2?autoReconnect=true'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1283)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1471)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:250)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.voiceforge.api.swift.VoiceManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/vf2?autoReconnect=true'
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/vf2?autoReconnect=true'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:382)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
    at com.voiceforge.api.dao.VoiceforgeDaoImpl.getVoiceList(VoiceforgeDaoImpl.java:86)
    at com.voiceforge.api.swift.VoiceManager.refreshVoices(VoiceManager.java:33)
    at com.voiceforge.api.swift.VoiceManager.<init>(VoiceManager.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/vf2?autoReconnect=true'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.acceptsURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:236)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:443)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: catalina.out actually reports what JAR file its looking for the class in? That sounds odd. Please add the exception stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Added, thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Hmmm, it's a NoClassDefFoundError, which is symptomatic of a class version incompatibility problem. You should check your class path for multiple versions of the MySQL JAR deployed, or possibly you have MySQL classes expanded somewhere in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing Tomcat 7 and the error went away. I do not know why the error presented itself unfortunately, but hopefully this may help some other people in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` can be symptomatic of many things, but the first thing to check for is that the class is actually on the classpath for your deployed webapp.

- Check that the MySQL connector JAR is in the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory, and check that it actually contains the class (`com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils`) that the exception says it cannot load.
- Check that there isn't a stray copy of the JAR file the webcontainer's core or shared library classpath.
- If the above fail to give a definite cause, check the logs for other (earlier) classloading exceptions.  There could be a nested exception for the one you've shown us.  There could be earlier exceptions.  For instance, if class initialization fails (due to an unchecked exception), then all subsequent attempts to load the class or related classes will throw an exception ... without re-reporting the original cause of the problem.

The other possibility is that your WAR file POM is merging in JARs that have conflicting dependencies.  Or that you are (in effect) allowing the conflicts further up the module build chain using dependency excludes.

---

There is a clue in the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/StringUtils
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:582)
    ....
```

Note that the `NoClassDefFoundError` is not being thrown in a `Class.forName(...)` call.  You should get hold of the source code fior the version of the JAR you are using, and see what it is doing at that line.

I suspect that this is throwing the exception because a previous attempt at class-loading has failed.  Are there any earlier stack-traces in the log files?

Comment: So I ran mvn dependency:tree and did not see the mysql jdbc jar listed as a dependency anywhere. I also checked in the WEB-INF/lib folder and did not find multiple versions of the jar. Is it possible that the shared tomcat6 libraries have an incompatible version?

Comment: also, gave the full stack trace.

Comment: Yes.  It is possible.  Did you check the shared tomcat6 directories for a mysql JAR?  Did you check that the mysql JAR that you found has that class in it?

Comment: There is no mysql connector jar. I was more worried that the class was packaged in one of the other jars located there.

Comment: If you are worried about that, you can always use the `jar` command to examine all of the JAR files.  But it seems unlikely, given what the StringUtils class actually does.  (It is very MySQL specific ...)

Comment: Yeah, I looked in all of them and found nothing. I am looking into your edit at the moment. I have looked in catalina and localhost logs to no avail unfortunately. Next I will look up the source as you pointed out.Its pretty frustrating to deal with these sorts of configuration errors >.<

Comment: It is possible that the original exception got "eaten"; e.g. if it was thrown on a thread that didn't have an uncaught exception handler to log it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's may not be the StringUtils class which can't be found.  That would probably manifest itself as a ClassNotFoundException.   NoClassDefFoundError is a little different, and my mean that something that StringUtils depends on can't be found.

Comment: I copy/pasted the full stack trace.